# How do I fetch the value from a key in firebase using javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: See the image i want to fetch this value in javascript]

```
 var dbImages = firebase.database().ref("images");

 dbImages.on("value", function(images){

    if(images.exists()){
        var imageshtml = ""; 
        images.forEach(function(fetchImages){

             console.log("key: " + fetchImages.key);
             console.log("title: " + fetchImages.title);
             console.log("url: " + fetchImages.url);

        });
     }

});
```

Its only showing key value not other value i want to view key value and also the value of key value please help guys

[image: This is the output of my javascript]

Comment: Hey Dharmaraj you also use console to view

Comment: Can you try using the code in my answer with nested forEach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `forEach()` and `DataSnapshot` of `/orders` node where each child node seems to be a category and not the image itself. You'll have to loop over each image of the categories to list them:

```
firebase.database().ref("images").once("value").then((imagesCategories) => {
  if (imagesCategories.exists()) {
    var imageshtml = "";

    // For each category
    imagesCategories.forEach(function(categoryImages) {
      // For each category image
      categoryImages.forEach(function(image) {
        // Append data to imageshtml from here
        console.log(image.val().url)
        console.log(image.val().title)
      })
    })
  }
});
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: firebase.database(...).ref(...).get is not a function

Comment: @AmitYadav sorry its `.ref("images").once("value")` and not get()

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

Comment: @AmitYadav right so can you use an async function or use promise chaining as in my updated answer... ? Also checkout async functions on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)